# UI/Utility for viewing the contents of chronicle queue/maps

Tags: java, java-8, chronicle, chronicle-queue, chronicle-map

Is there any UI or a utility through which we can check the contents of Chronicle Queues and Chronicle Maps?

Till now I have only found **DumpQueueMain** class which spits out all the info available on the queue.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is the Engine GUI which can view and update multiple maps and queues via web interface.

https://github.com/OpenHFT/Chronicle-Engine-GUI

It needs better documentation however.